# Changing the value of a variable at the end of a script

Tags: python, webdriver

I wrote a script that utilizing the following line of code:

```
for i in range(0, 677):
    a = i + 1
    b = i + 2
    c = i + 3
```

The script pulls data from 4 lines of my CSV at a time, the a,b,c are variables I use for pulling the data from the csv (lines 2,3,4) at the end of the script it loops and starts again. It's looping i + 1 each time the script runs. I need it to loop i + 4, what is the best way to do that?

To clarify, I want loop 1 to pull lines 1-4, loop 2 to pull lines 5-8, loop 3 to pull 9-12 etc

Comment: `range(0, 677, 4)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last (optional) argument for the `range` function allows you to specify an increment. So you can just use:

```
for i in range(0, 677, 4):
    a = i + 1
    b = i + 2
    c = i + 3
```